# Disable color in cardano-node logs

Tags: cardano-node, output

I am wondering, if it is possible to disable the colorization of the cardano-node logs.

Is it possible to disable the colors in the stdoutput of cardano-node?

[image: Screenshot of cardano node logs with colors]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible

```
cardano-node "rest of the command" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2};?)?)?[mGK]//g"
```

will do the trick. Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000433/17269751).

Comment: The proposed line does not disable colors in the cardano-node stdout/logs. This is removing the special sequences for colors.

I am looking for a configuration setting that omits the sequences used for colorized output. Which should happen automatically, when running in a non-interactive shell - but this is unfortunately not the case with the cardano-node CLI tool.